# how to put image on center on the page on every refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, splash-screen

I am working on HTML site I am facing problem is that when page load so splash screen is showing but when I load the same page the second time so splash screen is not showing and the image is not in the center of the page can you guys please help me how can I do this and one more thing when I increase the height of the image so it's not showing properly in mob view how can I do this please also tell me thanks.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
      <title></title>
      <meta name="author" content="Hitesh Sahu" />
      <style>

          /*

          */
          html, body, .viewport {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%; 
            margin: 0;
          }

          .flex-container {
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: -moz-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            -webkit-align-items: center;
            -moz-box-align: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
            -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -webkit-justify-content: center;
            -moz-box-pack: center;
            -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        #flex-item {
           text-align: center;
            margin: auto;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body  >

      <!--Your Main contents-->
      <div id ="main" class="flex-container"  
           style ="background: #673AB7;"> 

        <h2 style ="color: white;">Your Awesome contents<h2>

           </object>

     </div>

      <!--Your Splash Screen-->
      <div id="splash"  class="flex-container" 
            style ="background: #E91E63 ; display: none"  >

         <!--Center align Splash contents in all screen sizes-->
             <div id="flex-item" >
              <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGvaIWed26uYYryjCfO2qWpAFGrDyoWUlvCuPx-sEMAguMHcKQvw" 
                   alt="app_icon" 
                   style="width:150px ; height :150px"
                   />

               <h2 style ="color: white;">My Awesome App<h2>
             </div>
         </div>
      <!--  Scripts-->
      <script type="text/javascript">

        function fade(element) {
        var op = 1;  // initial opacity
        var timer = setInterval(function () {
            if (op <= 0.1){
                clearInterval(timer);

                element.style.display = 'none';
            }
            element.style.opacity = op;
            element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
            op -= op * 0.1;
        }, 50);
    }

        setTimeout(function(){ 

                 if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

                  console.log("Already shown" +sessionStorage.getItem('spalashShown'));

                   if( !sessionStorage.getItem('spalashShown') || sessionStorage.getItem('spalashShown') === null ) {  

                   document.getElementById('splash') .style.display = 'inline';

                    //Display splash
                    setTimeout(function(){   

                     fade(document.getElementById('splash'));
                      // document.getElementById('splash') .style.display = 'none'


                     sessionStorage.setItem('spalashShown', true  );
                  }
                   , 3000);

                      } else {

                         //Display Main Content
                          document.getElementById('splash') .style.display = 'none'
                            console.log("Already shown");
                         }
                      }

                    else {
                            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
                          }
                             }, 0);

        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using [localStorate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to check if splash screen has been displayed already.

To center image you can use `display: flex` with `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center`.

```js
function fade(element) {
  var op = 1; // initial opacity
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (op <= 0.1) {
      clearInterval(timer);

      element.style.display = 'none';
    }
    element.style.opacity = op;
    element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
    op -= op * 0.1;
  }, 50);
}

setTimeout(function() {
  //Display splash
  setTimeout(function() {
    fade(document.getElementById('splash'));
  }, 3000);
}, 0);
```

```css
html,
body,
.viewport {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#flex-item {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

#splash {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!--Your Main contents-->
<div id="main" class="flex-container" style="background: #673AB7;">

  <h2 style="color: white;">Your Awesome contents</h2>


  <!--Your Splash Screen-->
  <div id="splash" class="flex-container" style="background: #E91E63;">

    <!--Center align Splash contents in all screen sizes-->
    <div id="flex-item">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGvaIWed26uYYryjCfO2qWpAFGrDyoWUlvCuPx-sEMAguMHcKQvw" alt="app_icon" style="width:150px ; height :150px" />

      <h2 style="color: white;">My Awesome App</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: brother still its showing n the top of the page i want to show image in the center of the page and its also not showing on every refresh

Comment: Did you replace the content of `setTimeout()`?

Comment: The example I provided in my answer is working fine.

Comment: bro you can check your code in run script its showing image top of the page not center

Comment: I checked it on Chrome and Firefox. I run it and click on full page, the image is in the center.

Comment: dear just tell me how to make this image responsive your code is working now